# css transitions _without_ hover?

Tags: css, css-animations

Simple enough question:

Is it possible to leverage css transitions when it would would not be appropriate/feasible to trigger animations via pseudo selectors (ie `:hover`, `:active`, etc)?

My use case is I want something to animate after form submission.  I was thinking I would be able to do something like:

```
.success_message { ...transition stuff + opacity: 0 }
.success_message.shown { opacity: 1 }
```

Then using javascript, I would add the `shown` class to this element I want to animate.

Why not just use jQuery or similar to animate? I'm glad you asked. The CSS Transitions are much smoother on the iPhone and other mobile devices, which are the platforms I'm targeting. Currently I'm doing animations with jQuery, but they're just not as smooth as they could be.

---

Edited to clarify what I was asking about pseudo-selectors.

Comment: What do CSS transitions have to do with pseudo-class/element selectors?

Comment: Can you clarify what is not selectable via `:hover` or `:active`? As far I know, you can use these pseudo-selector on a lot of elements.

Comment: I believe OP is talking about events, as opposed to pseudo-selectors specifically.  E.g. "I want this to occur on a button click"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything should work as you expect.  JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghayes/zV9sc/12/

```
 .success_message {
   opacity: 0.0;
   transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
   -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;  
   -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
 }

 .success_message.shown {
   opacity: 1.0;
 }
```

If this does not solve your issue, please include further code samples or browser specifics.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I guess I just gave up too quickly when I was trying this the first time. Thanks for the example on JSFiddle. Excellent touch.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. Css transitions work any time a css property changes, even if it was because the class changed.

Comment: Thank you for the exceedingly quick and accurate reply, I appreciate it.